# Building webkit for osx from scratch

Tags: xcode, macos, browser, webkit

I want to build a basic browser with webkit. Does it need certain osx libraries to build? Where should I get the source and how should I compile it? How should I get started with webkit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [excellent document provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html) regarding development using WebKit. Also various good tutorials are [available throughout the Web](https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=webkit&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8RPqUpC5G4eQtQba5YGwCg#q=how%20to%20use%20webkit&rls=en).

Comment: What about the C++ API of webkit? I can only find ways of using the web view that is apart of the WebKit framework that Apple provides. I want to access the C++ api of the webkit source. Is there any documentation on that?